# angular/compiler-cli error on ng serve: cannot find module "rxjs/Observable"

Tags: angular

It was running fine until I wanted to push to heroku, then heroku gave me an error and said to update. So I did, then I'm getting this error on my local when I run `ng serve` or `npm start`. `The @angular/compiler-cli" package as not properly installed. Error: Error: cannot find module "rxjs/Observable"`

Things I've tried:

- ran `npm uninstall @angular/compiler-cli`
- then install `npm install --save-dev @angular/compiler-cli`
- installed rxjs

same error

- delete @angular/compiler-cli in `node_modules`
- install `npm install --save-dev @angular/compiler-cli`

Also ran `npm cache clean` and `npm cache clear` also tried it with `--force`

Answer (score 0):

In these kind of cases best thing is to delete `node_modules` (and `package-lock.json` if you have one, which you would if you have NPM 5), and run `npm install` again.

You'll need to have the `package.json` file as you had it at the last known good state for this to work. Assuming you are using git.

If this is a pet project and you didn't push to git etc, try creating a new Angular CLI project in a new folder and copying `src/` and `.angular-cli.json` to it. You might need to reinstall any 3rd party NPM packages your project used into the new project.